# Visual Studio 2015-Angular-Cordova-facebook login error

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-login, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

My Visual studio 2015 Cordova app, which uses facebook login is **working fine in Ripple emulator**. However, when I try to run the same app in Android emulator or in device, I get the error: “*Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*".

In my facebook settings (https://developers.facebook.com)  for website I have following entry:

Site URL: http://localhost:4400/
Mobile Site URL: http://localhost:4400/

In Advanced Tab, OAuth settings, both **Client OAuth Login** and Embedded **browser OAuth Login** are “yes”.
I tried with “Valid OAuth redirect URIs”  keeping  empty or http://localhost:4400/login

Hosts file does have an 127.0.0.1 localhost entry.

What should be the right URL in Site URL for an application in Basic and Advanced tab of http://developers.facebook.com? Wondering if these fields are ignored for a mobile app?

Comment: Have you tried the one mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#logindialog for desktop apps?

Answer (score 1):

Like on a device, when running in the Android emulator, the Android OS believes "localhost" is the device itself rather than your PC.  This is just like running Windows in a VM in this regard. Try fully qualifying your machine name or using an external IP instead.